# How to get GHCi to load the opengl package under GHC 7.6.1 x86-64 Windows 7?

Tags: opengl, haskell, ghci

I can successfully build executables that link against OpenGL using GHC, however, I cannot get the package to load into GHCi. This is definitely a regression for me because it works on 32-bit GHC (at least the version I upgraded from). I do not think the GHC version matters, just the fact that I am using the 64-bit GHC system.

On the recommendation of the maintainer, I explicitly brought the correct 64-bit version of opengl32 into GHCi successfully. It seems to be an issue higher up the stream.

Here is the output that is relevant. The verbose output is unfortunately just as specific. The function wglGetProcAddress is used to find where the OpenGL API hooks are in the dll.

```
$ ghcii.sh  -package OpenGL   
GHCi, version 7.6.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package OpenGLRaw-1.2.0.0 ... linking ... ghc.exe: unable to load package `OpenGLRaw-1.2.0.0'
ghc.exe: C:\...\cabal\OpenGLRaw-1.2.0.0\ghc-7.6.1\HSOpenGLRaw-1.2.0.0.o: unknown symbol `__imp_wglGetProcAddress'
```

Comment: Every package you install belongs to a specific version of ghc and will be invisible to other installed ghc versions.  Make sure that the ghc version that your ghcii.sh invokes has the openGL package in its corresponding package database for that ghc version.

Comment: This is most likely not the issue because A) GHC can build executables against the package and B) the error for not finding a package is entirely different from finding the package and not being able to resolve a symbol.

Comment: Oh, I thought the second error was a consequence of the first one, but now I understand the question better.  I don't know how much I can help if it is a ghci-specific problem, but you can see if you can get ghc to spit out what object files it uses when linking and try manually passing them to ghci on the command line.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but did you try the `-fno-ghci-sandbox` flag in GHCi? If you have any libraries that use thread local storage, GHCi will have trouble with them if you don't.

Comment: This question has been open for 7 years now, and all the mentioned versions are obsolete. Can we do something about it? I could answer with the recent tooling, but that will also be valid for some time only.